# What Port/s Does A Transiting Email use?

Tags: email

When I'm sending mail from say, outlook, outlook connects to my MX server @ port 25. But what port is the transiting mail destined to? Is it still 25?

Comment: what is your actual problem behind this question? What will be your benefit knowing the port number?

Comment: Can't I just be curious?

Comment: yes, you can. But giving a bit more background would increase the chance that people will find your question interesting and also you may get more useful answer.

Comment: I mean, that's really all there is to it I was just curious, but judging from your response, it must depend on the context. What context shall I provide?

Answer (score 0):

There is no transit email on protocol level. SMTP (the email protocol) is extremely primitive actually - it is ancient.

All sent emails are forwarded using the same protocol (SMTP) and thus the same port number. A transit it speficied by the server basically then sending the email further.